# Strange IP address connection from my computer

Tags: 16.04, networking, security

I have installed nethogs and it is showing a strange connection attempt in the logs

[image]

When I tried `dig -x`, it responds with suspicious looking addresses.

[image]

I don't know what these are. Please can you help out what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your browser (chrome) connecting to the IP 138.128.180.106, which is owned by a company called [HostDime](https://www.hostdime.com/).

Probably a website you visit is hosted by this company.

As the port is also 443, it is probably using HTTPS to access the website.

Comment: It shows without chrome as well. I have noticed it many times, for several days now.

Comment: And if I am browsing from chrome, wouldn't nethogs log this as connection from chrome?

Comment: It is shown as coming from chrome. Do you happen to know the site [Indiabix.com](http://www.indiabix.com/)?

Comment: Yeah I do. So it was coming from that site? But it was not from chrome, from firefox. Also,  how were you able to decode? And was it possible to find what it was trying to communicate? I had it on freeze. Was not browsing it.

Comment: It was not coming from that site. It was traffic from your computer to that site. I simply entered https://138.128.180.106 in the browser, and got to that site. Note that sockets may stick around for a while after a page is loaded.